# Manipulating csv data file using python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to work with data of NBA. That is why I have to make comparison. I need to get home win percentage. However it cannot convert string to int.

```
results["HomeWin"]=int(results["Home Team"])<int(results["OT?"])
y_true=results["HomeWin"].values
print("Home win percentage is{0:.1f}%".format(100*results["HomeWin"].sum()/results["HomeWin"].count()))
```

error is:cannot convert the series to type 'int'

Comment: use `astype(int)` : `results["HomeWin"]=results["Home Team"].astype(int)<results["OT?"].astype(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need cast by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) `string` numbers to `int`:

```
results["HomeWin"] = results["Home Team"].astype(int) < results["OT?"].astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.DataFrame({'Home Team':['1','2','3'],
                   'OT?':['4','2','1']})

print (results)
  Home Team OT?
0         1   4
1         2   2
2         3   1


results["HomeWin"] = results["Home Team"].astype(int) < results["OT?"].astype(int)
print (results)
  Home Team OT?   HomeWin
0         1   4      True
1         2   2     False
2         3   1     False
```

Comment: it gives error as: invalid literal for long() with base 10: 'November'

Comment: There is problem you have string data in columns like `November` which cannot be converted to number. You can check this problematic values by `print (results.ix[pd.to_numeric(results["Home Team"], errors='coerce').isnull() | pd.to_numeric(results["OT?"], errors='coerce').isnull(), ['Home Team','OT?']])`

Comment: You can check it by `results = pd.DataFrame({'Home Team':['1','2','3', 'November'],
                   'OT?':['4','September','1', '5']})`